# transform employment data in R - from wide to long

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have the following data

```
employed_male; unemployed_male; inactive_male; employed_female; unemployed_female; inactive_female;
```

i want to change it to

```
gender; status; value
```

For example:

```
employed_male; unemployed_male; inactive_male; employed_female; unemployed_female; inactive_female;
5;             4;                6;            7;               3;                 1;
```

will be

```
gender; status; value
male; employed; 5
male; unemployed; 4
male; inactive; 6
female; employed; 7
female; unemployed; 3
female; inactive; 1
```

Do you know, which library or approach is best to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot_longer` you can use :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 
                    cols = everything(), 
                    names_to = c('status', 'gender'),
                    names_sep = '_')

#  status     gender value
#  <chr>      <chr>  <int>
#1 employed   male       5
#2 unemployed male       4
#3 inactive   male       6
#4 employed   female     7
#5 unemployed female     3
#6 inactive   female     1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(employed_male = 5L, unemployed_male = 4L,inactive_male = 6L,
    employed_female = 7L, unemployed_female = 3L, inactive_female = 1L),
    row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score -1):

`tidyr::pivot_longer()` is a good choice. See [this section of the documentation](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html#many-variables-in-column-names).